# Oracle view performance on different schemas

Tags: oracle, performance, view

I have an oracle view which gets data from 3 different tables (using dblinks): 2 of them are in schema A and the third one on schema B (both schemas are on the same SID)

I have initially created my view on a third schema (C). The view was working normally (let's say fast)

Then i moved the view from schema C to schema A (where 2 of the queried tables are located), and everything became super slow

Why is this happening? I would have expected thing to be faster (since now the view is "closer" to the tables)
What can i do to make it faster?

This is the query of the view (in it's initial version on schema C, where each table had to use a dblink):

```
SELECT 
    e.ute, 
    e.fonte, 
    e.nr_key, 
    g.numero,
    e.tipo_flusso,
    g.data_fattura, 
    e.row_instime as engine_last_instime,
    e.spedita_il as ultimo_invio,
    substr(e.xml_file_name,0,19) as last_xml,
    g.cf_cessionario, 
    g.ragsoc_cessionario,
    e.status_id, 
    s.cod_status,
    e.rielaborare,
    case
        when rielaborare = -1 then 'ANNULLATA'
        when rielaborare = 9 then 'OK' --serve per gestire le NO_RECAPITO risolte
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPA%' and e.status_id in (0,1,2,3,4,9,99) then 'IN ATTESA'
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPA%' and e.status_id in (5,7) then 'OK'
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPA%' and e.status_id in (6,8,10,11) then 'KO'
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPR%' and e.status_id in (0,1,2,3,99) then 'IN ATTESA'
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPR%' and e.status_id in (4,5,7,9) then 'OK'
        when e.tipo_flusso like 'FPR%' and e.status_id in (6,8,10,11) then 'KO'
        else '???'
    end as esito,
    case
        when e.fonte = 'Net@SIU' then lower(e.ute)||'_'||lower(substr(nr_key, 0, instr(nr_key, '-')-1))||'_'||substr(nr_key, instr(nr_key, '-')+1, 4)||'_'||to_number(substr(nr_key, instr(nr_key, '-',1,2)+1))
        when e.fonte = 'Net@H2O' then replace(nr_key,'MR','01')
        when e.fonte = 'invoicex' then 'ise'||substr(nr_key,0,4)||lpad(substr(nr_key, instr(nr_key, '/',1,2)+1), 8, '0')
        when e.fonte = 'Net@DIS' then lower(nr_key)
        else null
    end as d3_pk_boltes,
    d3_file_name
FROM
    fattura_pa@d3web2fe_engine e,
    fattura_pa_status@d3web2fe_engine s,
    fatture@d3web2fe_gateway g
WHERE 
    g.direz_fatt(+) = 'A'    --prende solo le fatture attive
    and nvl(g.duplicata,0) = 0   --esclude gli invii scartati per fattura duplicata (la condition é ripetuta poi anche nella subquery successiva, perché ci sono dei casi di invio contemporaneo con scarto per fattura duplicata)
    and e.progressivo_invio = g.progressivo_invio(+)
    and e.status_id = s.id    
    and e.row_instime = (
        --per ciascun documento, prende l'invio piú recente, escludendo peró l'eventuale scarto derivato da fattura duplicata
        select max(e2.row_instime) 
        from 
        fattura_pa@d3web2fe_engine e2,
        fatture@d3web2fe_gateway g2
        where e.ute = e2.ute and e.nr_key = e2.nr_key
        and g2.direz_fatt(+) = 'A'
        and e2.progressivo_invio = g2.progressivo_invio(+)
        and nvl(g2.duplicata,0) = 0
    );
```

Comment: can you provide the `explain plan` of the view ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'are on the SID'? you mean same database? if so, why are you using dblinks? Is the view in a different database?

Comment: Yes they are on the same database, and even on the same SID. I am using dblinks because they are on different schemas... shouldn't I? Are there other ways to do this?